# No 'Child Pane' option in settings bundle root

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've added a settings bundle to the app using Xcode 6.3.1. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) I should be able to create hierarchical structure by adding the 'Child Pane' key (`PSChildPaneSpecifier`) to a `.plist` file (`Root.plist` in my case).

Unfortunately, there's no such option in the drop-down menu (I have not enough reputation to post the screenshot, sigh) — I get all the other options mentioned in the docs, though. Did anyone experience similar problems? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Child pane is not available as a drop down option. You need to add it manually to the `Preference Items` array in `Root.plist`. The type should be `PSChildPaneSpecifier`. This became `Child Pane` automatically for me.

```
Type        String        Child Pane
Title       String        Your title here
Filename    String        fileName
```

The `fileName` should not include a path or `.plist` extension.

Next you need to add the new file for the nested layer of settings. From the `File` menu add a new `plist` file and ensure it is in your settings bundle.

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click in the editor pane -> Property List Type -> iPhone Settings Plist.

Add a row for `Preference Items` and set it as an array. Then add your dictionaries for each item nested inside this. You can copy the default Root.plist for the structure.

You can find more information from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSChildPaneSpecifier.html).